# Handling Files in Git that need to different in every branch

Tags: git, configuration, merge

I'm asking myself how to handle the following situation.

I have two different branches on two different production systems with config xml files in a folder that I want in Git and need to be different. Now we always merge from a development branch into the two branches.

Now I'm afraid, somebody might merge the wrong config files into one of the production branches.

How should I handle these kind of sitiuations? I don't want to .gitignore the files and handle them manually...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Lets call the branches dev, prod1 and prod2.

As long as you only ever merge dev->prod1 and dev->prod2 you will have no problems and local changes to $file.xml in either prod1 or prod2 will be kept just fine and independently from each other.

Should someone merge prod1->dev or prod2->dev you will get problems at some point.
Same thing for prod1->prod2 and prod2->prod1.

I usually work in small teams and just tell people not to do merges the wrong way round and that's it. If you work in some enterprisey corporation where such things need to be automated you could come up with some hooks that enforce this, but personally i think this is overkill.

Comment: is there any way of preventing merge directions other then telling everybody in the team? I guess with write permissions on branches

Comment: git's permission system is virtually non-existent. if you can reach a clone you can do whatever you want with it. you can provide some hooks that stop cooperating users from some accidents, and some repository management software like gitolite gives you some control what can be pushed to a central repository.

Answer (score 0):

I usually keep configuration files that depend on a certain environment in separate "contrib" folders. So I can have them under version control but I have to copy them to the expected location (manually). I usually add "setup" scripts to the contrib folders:

```
./
  contrib/
          prod1/
                application.config
                prepare.sh
          prod2/
                application.config
                prepare.bat
          team1/
                application.config
                prepare.bat
          team2/
                application.config
                prepare.sh
```

The example assumes that the production systems use different operating systems and require different "prepare" scripts (to copy the config file(s) and do other stuff) and that teams with different development environments work on the same project.

Comment: that's what I could do if I want to hanlde them manually, but I'd like them in git. So I if the files are updated I can't forget to upload them...

Comment: @spankmaster79 This is that you should do. Otherwise I don't understand what do you want from git. You need files to be differ, but the git is good on merging differences. What kind of help do you expect from git?

Comment: @spankmaster79 - maybe that wasn't clear enough: the contrib folder is under version control. All "instances" of the config files and scripts are checked in.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `update` hook on the repos where you do not want changes from other branches leaking into `prod1` and `prod2`. In the `update` hooks you can check which paths are being affected by a push and reject it if you do not want those paths touched.

That solution will in practice prevent *any* modification of those xml files, which I guess is not exactly what you want (if the files are under version control surely you want to be able to create new versions of them). In order to overcome this limitation, you can grant one user with permissions to push changes to those files.

The Git Book contains an [example](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy) of how to create an `update` hook on a Git repo, including how to obtain the user name (both for SSH and other kinds of access). Check out the link for more info on how to actually write the hook. Remember that hooks are just executable files (or scripts), so you can actually write them in the language of your choice.